# how to update data after collection in firebase firestore - flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Am trying to update my firestore database. It is a chat database where am trying to update the chat message if it is read or unread and this is my code

```
updateIsread(String receiverId, String chatRoomId) async {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("chatRoom")
        .doc(chatRoomId)
        .collection("chats")
        .where('sendTo', isEqualTo: receiverId);
  }
```

The problem is that after **.collection("chats")** i can't use **.update()**
Please help me out and this is my firebase structure
[image]

[image]

Comment: does debug console gives you `permission denied` message?

Comment: @SimonSot no not really it doesn't it just shows like a syntax error that `.update` can't be used after `.collection("chats")`

Comment: Oh right, that is because `where` returns you `Query` that represents location in databse, the reason here is that the result may be multiple documents. You need to get the first one, get its `DocumentReference` and then use update on it. I'll try to find something similar for you in my project, I think there I had something like this long time ago.

Comment: @SimonSot ok let me try that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to get a `QuerySnapshot` first, then from first document in it you can know [`DocumentReference`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference-class.html) and use [`update`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/update.html) on it:

```
await QuerySnapshot _querySnapshot = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("chatRoom")
        .doc(chatRoomId)
        .collection("chats")
        .where('sendTo', isEqualTo: receiverId).get();
if (_querySnapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) await _querySnapshot.docs[0]
                                         .reference
                                         .update('YourUpdateData');
```

There might be a better way for doing this, but thats what worked for me.

Comment: So where did the `documentSnapshot.docs[0]` come from, cause its giving me an error

Comment: @Brightcode Sorry! Was part of my code! I corrected it.

Comment: Ok let me just run it and see

Comment: I do recommend reading Batch updates >> "https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#batch-write". Just in case further down the line you plan to update a bunch of documents instead of 1, so you don't burn through your read/write operations.

Comment: @O.Cuenca I actually did use a batch update but i keep getting this error `Unhandled Exception: Bad state: This batch has already been committed and can no longer be changed.`

Comment: @O.Cuenca this is my code `WriteBatch batch = FirebaseFirestore.instance.batch();
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("chatRoom")
        .doc(chatRoomId)
        .collection("chats")
        .where('sendTo', isEqualTo: receiverId)
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) {
      if (querySnapshot.docs.isNotEmpty)
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
          batch.update(document.reference, {"isread": true});
        });
    });
    return batch.commit();`

Comment: @Brightcode this error usually happends when you create `batch` instance in scope of multiple repository functions, create new batch instance for every operation in its own scope.

Comment: @SimonSot Please how do i do that

Comment: @Brightcode create async function like  `sendMessageUpdate`, inside of it start of with creating new batch instance, do all needed operations with it, and commit batch in the end. Thats all. Your function on invocation will create and use unique new batch instance.